# How to call external script from X3D and get data back?

Tags: javascript, php, scripting, external, x3d

I want to call external PHP script from X3D model. And get result to the variable in X3D.
As I read, this maybe can be done on JS.

```
Script { 
            url [ "http://example.com/myScript.php",
                  "ecmascript: function foo() { ... }" ]
        }
```

Is it right? Are there any full code examples, will it work at all?

Comment: Here is the code  ```<script type="text/javascript">
 
X3D (function ()
{
  // Now, X3D is ready. We can get access to the browser object.
 
  var Browser = X3D .getBrowser ("X3DCanvas.browser");
 
  browser .loadURL (new X3D .MFNode ("/path/to/your/world.x3dv"),
                    new X3D .MFNode ());
});
 
</script>``` Can we load PHP here to the scene as output to variable?

Comment: ```-<![CDATA[ecmascript:

function initialize ()
{
 // Phong shading can be enabled if »X_ITE Compatibility« mode is enabled in Titania.

 Browser .setBrowserOption ("Shading", "PHONG");
X3D (function ()
{
  // Now, X3D is ready. We can get access to the browser object.
 
  var Browser = X3D.getBrowser ("X3DCanvas.browser");
 
  browser .loadURL (new X3D .MFNode ("http://google.ru"),
                    new X3D .MFNode ());
});


}
]]>``` Is this code correct? I'm trying to load an url