# How can I change contents of X3D scene via Javascript with PHP or HTML load?

Tags: javascript, php, external, x3d, x3dom

I want to create a scene on X3D with calls to HTML or PHP script. For changing the content of the scene.
The question is rather simple and interesting. It's different from another one cause of adding details about code and concrete question on how to load x3d into the browser. T**he code example here is rather different comparing my other question.**

First of all, will .x3d work in the browser without putting on .html file?
Now I have such a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Touchsensor in X3DOM</title>

    <link href="x3dom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
    #myDiv {
        color: blue;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    x3d {
        display: block;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background: #EEEEEE;
        border: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="myDiv">
        Click the sphere to hide this div
    </div>

    <x3d>
        <Scene>
            <Shape id="mySphere">
                <Appearance>
                    <Material diffuseColor="0 1 0" />
                </Appearance>
                <Sphere/>
            </Shape>
        </Scene>
    </x3d>


    <script src="x3dom.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function() {

        document.getElementById('mySphere').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = "none";
// HERE I WANT TO PUT CALLS TO PHP OR HTML SCRIPT
// WILL IT WORK AT ALL? AJAX IS ON THE MIND
        };

    })();
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

X3dom.js is what a file? How to load PHP file and where to get this .js?
It's seems realizable - but can someone confirm?

Comment: Hi @Konstantin. So, yes, all of this is doable. But to me it seems that you would need start a bit differently by learning the basics of Javascript, PHP and HTML and how you could upload dynamically load generated content to your webpage. It also depends on the framework you might want to use and many more. You question as of right now is a bit wide and needs to be narrowed down.

Comment: Thanks! Hello. I have 14 years experience of AJAX, PHP, HTML, so all this Is real. But X3D is new for me, so am I asking it, how to do a call function. The main is here the syntax - right - of the command

Comment: For ex., this function to get data must be simple AJAX or X3D-documented special?

Comment: Also x3dom.js - must we load it from somewhere ot it will catch automatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call external script from X3D and get data back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476349/how-to-call-external-script-from-x3d-and-get-data-back)

Comment: So, yes, you can apply common Javascript techniques here. Just do an XHR and use the result to update your scene. The basic examples from https://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/basics/htmlCSS/index.html should give a good hint.

Comment: Thanks for this - this is my old topic. But I pasted AJAX <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
$('#digital_download').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."
// Do an ajax request
$.ajax({
  url: "http://google.ru"
}).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
  $('#digital_download').html(data); // display data
}); And it's not working

Comment: More over, the example of scene X3D working nonstable. Sphere works, box is not showed.